# Is this too much abstraction?

Tags: oop

Some may know where the source code below comes from (though it's be simplified). The question is, when does the security scopes constant become "worthwhile" in OOP.

```
class Authenticate
{
    // The permissions to request.
    private static $CLASS_SCOPES = [
        Service1:Permission1; <-- valuable here? I think not.
        Service1:Permission2; <-- valuable here? maybe, but I think not.
        Service1:Permission3; <-- valuable here?
        Service1:Permission4; <-- valuable here? etc...
    ];
    public function run($pathToJsonFile, $email = null)
    {
        // Create an authenticated client object.
        $client = $this->createAuthenticatedClient($pathToJsonFile, $email);
        // Create a service object.
        $service = new Service($client);
        $this->non-existent_function_do_something($service);
    }
    private function createAuthenticatedClient($pathToJsonFile, $email)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('service sample');
        $client->setScopes(self::$CLASS_SCOPES);
        // Load the service account credentials.
        $client->setAuthConfig($pathToJsonFile);
        return $client;
    }
}
```

I know many users first thought is "This question is too broad" or "Out of scope of this site". But I think those are excuses for not trying to abstract the logic of good OOP design. Where does the cutoff fall? I tried to make a very specific question that outlines(or begins to) a general guide for when it's worthwhile to take a procedural portion of code and encapsulate it.

Comment: Are you asking for reasons to have the scope array? Instead of... a temporary array in the function? What does this have to do with abstraction?